# PHP How to extract part of given string?

Tags: php, regex, extract

I'm writing a search engine for my site and need to extract chunks of text with given keyword and few words around for the search result list.
I ended with something like that:

```
/**
 * This function return part of the original text with
 * the searched term and few words around the searched term
 * @param string $text Original text
 * @param string $word Searched term
 * @param int $maxChunks Number of chunks returned
 * @param int $wordsAround Number of words before and after searched term
 */
public static function searchTerm($text, $word=null, $maxChunks=3, $wordsAround=3) {
        $word = trim($word);
        if(empty($word)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        $words = explode(' ', $word); // extract single words from searched phrase
        $text  = strip_tags($text);  // clean up the text
        $whack = array(); // chunk buffer
        $cycle = 0; // successful matches counter
        foreach($words as $word) {
            $match = array();
            // there are named parameters 'pre', 'term' and 'pos'
            if(preg_match("/(?P\w+){0,$wordsAround} (?P$word) (?P\w+){0,$wordsAround}/", $text, $match)) {
                $cycle++;
                $whack[] = $match['pre'] . ' ' . $word . ' ' . $match['pos'];
                if($cycle == $maxChunks) break;
            }
        }
        return implode(' | ', $whack);
    }
```

This function does not work, but you can see the basic idea. Any suggestions how to improve the regular expression is welcome!

Comment: Why do you split the string if you want several words around ?

Comment: The whole construction looks way too complicated in my opinion. Do you really need to cut the text at word boundaries? You could simply use PHPs [`substr()`-function](http://php.net/substr) otherwise. Using plain variables in regular expressions is a bit problematic, too. Take a look at [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) or use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: In this line: *if($cycle == $maxCycles) continue;* you use the variable *$maxCycles*. I think you would actually want to put *$maxChunks* there, don't you?

Comment: @MatTheCat - I'd like to search for every possible word in the phrase, not the exact phrase
@elusive - yes. It wouldn't look good, if the words were cut 
@slosd - you are right

Answer (score 1):

Never, *never* inject user content into the pattern of a RegEx without using preg_quote to sanitize the input:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: OK, that's one suggestion, but if the regular does not work, this is not critical. Thanks anyway, I'll put the preg_quote in.

Comment: Are you trying to _optimize_ the RegEx or _fix_ it?

Comment: I'm no friend of regular expressions, so this was my first idea but I wasn't able to move on and make i work the right way

Answer (score 1):

why re-invent the wheel here doesn't google have the best search engine I would look at their [appliance](http://www.google.com/enterprise/)

Comment: I know they have it and I like the way they have it. But I was hoping to solve the problem with one lightweight function, not the whole third party's search engine..